# How to link a shared library without having to export its internal targets

Tags: cmake

The following repro cmake project fail to configure. The goal is to create a shared library that internally consists of a couple of static libraries. I want the internal symbols and include paths etc to be exported from the shared library. To do that I make the internal libs PUBLIC link libraries. But then cmake tells me I need to export my target. I don't want to "pollute" my package config with a bunch of internal targets. Is there no way to "merge" internal targets (static libs) into the public exported target (shared lib) or hide it in the config targets file?

The SystemC::systemc imported target does not show up in my target file and it also don't generate any error. I assume that is because this target is already exported in its own package? If so, would that mean I need to make my internal libs packages and so imported targets to make them go away from my exported targets list?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(mylib)

find_package(SystemCLanguage 2.3.3 CONFIG REQUIRED)

add_library(mysublib STATIC mysublib.cpp)

add_library(mylib SHARED mylib.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mylib
    PUBLIC SystemC::systemc
    PUBLIC mysublib
)

export(
    TARGETS mylib
    NAMESPACE MyLib::
    FILE MyLibTargets.cmake
)
```

Error generated at configure

```
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  export called with target "mylib" which requires target "mysublib" that is
  not in any export set.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The goal is to create a shared library that internally consists of a couple of static libraries. I want the internal symbols and include paths etc to be exported from the shared library. To do that I make the internal libs PUBLIC link libraries.

So, first, I'll note that `PUBLIC` has nothing at all to do with symbol visibility. Your example `mysublib` doesn't have any `INTERFACE` properties, so you could make it `PRIVATE` to `mylib` and avoid the need to export `mysublib`.

However, if you *do* need `mysublib` in the `INTERFACE` of `mylib`, then you *do* need to export it, period. There is no way to, as you say "'merge' internal targets [...] into the public exported target [...] or hide it in the config targets file". But this is also not a real problem.

If you're concerned about people relying on `mysublib`, then you can set the `EXPORT_NAME` property of `mysublib` to something that indicates it's not meant to be used, like `_private_mysublib`:

```makefile
set_target_properties(mysublib PROPERTIES EXPORT_NAME _private_mysublib)
```

If you want to be *really* aggressive about it, you could even make the name random:

```makefile
string(RANDOM LENGTH 12 mysublib_export)
set_target_properties(mysublib PROPERTIES EXPORT_NAME "x${mysublib_export}")
```

Prepending an `x` makes sure it doesn't start with a number. There is also a remote chance of collision if you do this a lot. If you want to be absolutely safe, you should write a function that records the names it's already returned in a global property and tries again if it chooses a collision.

> The SystemC::systemc imported target does not show up in my target file and it also don't generate any error. I assume that is because this target is already exported in its own package? If so, would that mean I need to make my internal libs packages and so imported targets to make them go away from my exported targets list?

You are correct: because `SystemC::systemc` is imported, it does not need to be (and in fact *cannot* be) re-exported. You're expected to call `find_dependency(SystemCLanguage 2.3.3)` in your `MyLibConfig.cmake` file, both within the build tree (`export`) and after install (`install(EXPORT)`).

If you want this behavior to apply to `mysublib`, then *yes*, you will need to split your projects apart. I don't see a compelling reason to do that, though. Either make `mysublib` `PRIVATE` or just live with it being renamed in your package config. Targets aren't precious and they're namespaced, so there's no real reason to worry.

Comment: I'm used to Makefiles which are more direct, do this, get that. I guess cmake tries to future proof itself if I for example would change mysublib to be SHARED. Now I just need to figure out how to get dependencies (dlls) into the target (exe) build folder so ctest can run the built targets...

Comment: Try `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`